# Opening a view controller from a mail file but not the whole app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to open an view controller but not the whole app when I select it from a file? Every time I select the file I open the whole app and I cannot dismiss it. Wunderlist  does it. This it how it looks like

[image: This is Wunderlist’s behavior.]

I cannot subclass UIDocumentInteractionController there is no way I can make it work.

Thanks

Comment: what is the link that you open when wanderlust appears?

Comment: It al txt file. I can open it too, but I open my whole application. I only want to call a UIViewController without launching the whole app.